# MySQL throws syntax error near `INNER JOIN SQL`

Tags: mysql, sql

I have to get the name and hacker_id from of hackers with a full score on at least 2 or more challenges. This is my code and the error code that I keep getting, but I can't figure out what to do next to correct it.

```
SELECT DISTINCT hacker_id, name
FROM hackers
WHERE hacker_id in
 (SELECT s.score, hacker_id
  FROM submissions as s
  INNER JOIN 
  difficulty as d
  on s.score=d.score
  GROUP BY hacker_id
  HAVING count(hacker_id)>1) as x
INNER Join hackers as h
ON x.hacker_id=h.hacker_id
ORDER BY COUNT(challenge_id) DESC, hacker_id ASC;
```

> ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 21: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'as x
> inner Join hackers as h
> on x.hacker_id=h.hacker_id
> order by count(challenge' at line 10

Comment: `WHERE` has to come *after* `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: You can also just join with the subquery instead of using `WHERE hacker_id IN`

Comment: Your query has several other issues too. 1) The GROUP BY is invalid. 2) The IN wants a one column result set. 3) The count() is not available in the ORDER BY,.

Comment: You can't use `ON x.hacker_id` because the `x` subquery isn't a table you joined with.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to use both JOIN and WHERE IN for the same thing. Pick one or the other.

Comment: I never us as for table aliases - I don't know whether that could throw an error

Answer (score 3):

Just use a simple join with `submissions`, with grouping in the main query.

Use `COUNT(DISTINCT s.challenge_id)` to count the number of challenges they submitted for.

```
SELECT h.hacker_id, h.name
FROM hackers AS h
JOIN submissions AS s ON s.hacker_id = h.hacker_id
JOIN difficulty AS d ON s.score = d.score
GROUP BY h.hacker_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT s.challenge_id) > 1
ORDER BY COUNT(DISTINCT s.challenge_id) DESC, hacker_id ASC
```

You don't need `SELECT DISTINCT` because `GROUP BY h.hacker_id` ensures that the rows will be distinct.

Comment: Does MySQL also want h.name in the GROUP BY clause if ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY is enabled?

Comment: It's not needed if `hacker_id` is the primary key of the table.

Comment: That's nice. Thank you for the information.